# To create Java project with Spring persistence using Maven?

Tags: java, spring, maven-2

Is it good idea to create Java project with Spring persistence using Maven?

What maven archetype to use? 
AppFuse is seemed to be freezed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You an use Spring ROO to create a Spring project based on Maven.

Comment: and: yes, it is a good idea to use Spring and Maven together.

Comment: The Spring Tool Suite (STS), provide Spring Template Projects (for different Type of projects), the newer Versions (> 2.5) are Maven based projects.

Answer (score 2):

The principle of a Maven archetype is to create a skeleton of an application based on some specificities (for example the usage of `Spring` in your case).

This skeleton will generate the root `pom.xml`, the basic directories structure (`src/main/resources`, `src/main/java`, and so on), as well as some other files, which are specific to the archetype used, such as the `applicationContext.xml` in the Spring case.

Of course, this is only a skeleton (which is however generally runnable to get some `Hello World` stuff), so you will have to adapt it to your precise requirements: change the `pom.xml` content (for example the versions of third libraries), add or remove some configuration files...

Maybe you can give a try to any AppFuse archetype (what do you mean by *freezed* by the way?), and then remove everything that is not needed in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you r using Netbeans 6.8 then follow below one

New Project->Maven->Maven PRoject->Default Archetype Catalog-> A simple J2EE Java application

Remove Other unused modules and modify it as per ur requirement...